# create "down" panel in HTML page (split view)

Tags: java, jquery, html, cordova

I'm a new in web development, and I'm trying to create app for iphone by use phonegap,

I want to be in the home page two split view , i found a "panel" way , but it's create "left" or "right" view only , i want to create "up" and "down" view, i want to be in the first view some paragraph text, and a "button" to open the second view from "down" and the whole page will split to first view in the "up" and the second view in the "down".

and create another button in top bar to cancel the second view .. see picture

[image: split]

how can i do that ? is it with javascript or jquery mobile ?

thanks